# How to enable RN debug mode other than debug build variant

Tags: react-native, debugging, build-type

I have multiple build variants in my RN project and debug in physical device

```
productFlavors{
   gms{
      applicationIdSuffix ".gms"
   }
   hms{
      applicationIdSuffix ".hms"
   }
}

buildTypes{
   debug{ ... }
   staging{...}
   release{...}
}
```

When I run `react-native run-android --variant=hmsdebug --appIdSuffix=hms`, I'm able access into RN debugging mode with auto bundled js code and start hot reloading.

However, if I run `react-native run-android --variant=hmsstaging --appIdSuffix=hms` and I get the error of `unable loading script`. Then I have to run `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle` myself to generate the bundle js and re-run `react-native run android ...` to get it work, but it fails to access debugging mode and throw error `no device connected`.

What is the proper way to let me able to access debugging mode in other android build variant?